# Can I localize the dynamically changing string/text in cocoa

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, localization

I have understood the concept of internationalization a little in XCode4.The steps are

1.Add string file to the project

2.From the inspector panel of this string file,under localization sections,select the required localization languages from the list.

3.Consider I have added English and French.

4.If I want to localize the string Hello,I need to add key value pair in the relevant string Files like "Title" = "Hello" in Localizable.Sring(English) and "Title" = "Bonjour" in Localizable.Sring(French)

5.Then,We can read the localization text of English and French using NSLocalizedString(@"Title", nil);

This works fine.

Here is my requirement,I am reading a string from the Web services,I don't know the string and the length of the string,it might be a paragraph.It may be varying each time I send the request.

I need to read this text which is changing at runtime and covert to into required localized string lets consider French.How can I do this.Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: You want a universal translator?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you know all possible strings. Why not using:

```
NSString *myDynamicString = ...
NSLocalizedString(myDynamicString, "dynamic string");
```

Comment: This is not working for me.As a sample I am reading the text from the textfield.I set the language type to french and launched my Application.I typed Hello in the textfield and clicked on the button to take the following action.Still It is Hello(English text) not a french text                                           -(IBAction)displayText:(id)sender
{
    NSString *inputString = [inputTextDisplay stringValue];
    
    NSString* str= NSLocalizedString(inputString, "dynamic string");
    NSLog(@"English Language is %@",str);
    [textDisplay setStringValue:str];
}

Comment: That means We should know the strings before we localize it.We can't do localization for the text which we don't know right?

Comment: Yes, of cause. There is no universal translator build in :)  You have to put this in your fresh string file: "hello" = "bonjour"; and in the english one simply "hello" = "hello";